# Confusion about start end index in binary search

Tags: javascript, binary-search

Following is the binary search from this [post](http:////https://medium.com/@jeffrey.allen.lewis/javascript-algorithms-explained-binary-search-25064b896470). `s` means start index, `e` means end index. I think I understand them.

```
function bs(arr, tar) {
  let s = 0;
  let e = arr.length - 1;

  while(s <= e) {
    let m = Math.floor((s + e) / 2);

    if(tar === arr[m]) {
      return m;
    }

    if(tar > arr[m]) {
      s = m + 1; // follow index
    }

    if(tar < arr[m]) {
      e = m - 1; // follow index
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let tar = 5;
let out = bs(arr, tar);
console.log(out);
```

Sometimes I also see this version:

```
function bs(arr, tar) {
  let s = 0;
  let e = arr.length; // full len

  while(s < e) {
    let m = Math.floor((s + e) / 2);

    if(tar === arr[m]) {
      return m;
    }

    if(tar > arr[m]) {
      s = m + 1; // because s=0;
    }

    // end, exact index
    if(tar < arr[m]) {
      e = m; // not m-1, because arr.length???
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let tar = 5;
let out = bs(arr, tar);
console.log(out);
```

I think after a while, I get what the indexes mean.

Comment: and your question/problem is?

Comment: Consider using a debugger to step through the code line-by-line in order to understand what's going on. Or by writing down an example on paper and going through the algorithm by hand until you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search need an ordered list to work, for example a list of numbers. The idea is to search an element in the right half and this is possible because this algorithm converge to one. Let's say that you have a list of 10(1, 10, 54, 70, 100, 110, 120, 130, 150, 200)numbers and you are looking for  120. You divide list into two halves and look for the middle element (100) is 120 greater than 100? Yes so the element is in the second half, now start point is middle position and end position is the end of the list, you go on until you have an element, the one you are looking for. Hope this was helpful